# upgrading to Apache 2.4: VirtualHost Invalid command 'AssignUserID'

Tags: virtualhost, freebsd, migration, apache-2.4

I have many Apache 2.2 Virtual Hosts with same configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@site.com
    ServerName  site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /home/site.com/htdocs/
    ErrorLog     /home/site.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog    /home/site.com/logs/access.log common
    AssignUserID site.com ftp
    <Directory /home/site.com/htdocs/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I get errors when trying to run the same configuration on Apache 2.4:

```
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes/site.com.conf:
Invalid command 'AssignUserID', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included   in the server configuration
```

Unfortunately I could not find a way to use my configuration with Apache 2.4. Help solve the problem.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Which modules have you enabled? You obviously need to load the mpm-itk module for that to work.

Comment: I installed on the new server Apache 2.4 and trying to use VirtualHost configuration files from Apache 2.2. Unfortunately there is no option  Apache 2.4 with ITK_MPM, there are options MPM_PREFORK, MPM_WORKER, MPM_EVENT. I use FreeBSD 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the maintainer of the port apache24:

```
You need to load mpm-itk into apache 2.4. There is pending port with
mpm-itk for apache 2.4:

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188992

It's waiting for almost three months for some good soul to pick it up :)
```

...
Sun Jul 13 23:21:42 UTC 2014 added a new port:

```
- new port mod_mpm_itk for apache24

  apache2-mpm-itk (just mpm-itk for short) is an MPM (Multi-Processing Module)
  for the Apache web server. mpm-itk allows you to run each of your vhost
  under a separate uid and gid - in short, the scripts and configuration files
  for one vhost no longer have to be readable for all the other vhosts.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with FreeBSD but you'll somehow have to install MPM-ITK for apache 2.4. For instance, in Ubuntu it would be something like `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk`

Then, the MPM-ITK module must be enabled in the apache configuration. Uncomment/adding the line below should do the job.

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module /path/to/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_itk.so
```

Also, `allow from all` no longer works in apache2.4; should be `Require all granted`. The vhost below should work once you've installed `mpm-itk`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@site.com
    ServerName  site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /home/site.com/htdocs/
    ErrorLog     /home/site.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog    /home/site.com/logs/access.log common
    AssignUserID site.com ftp
    <Directory /home/site.com/htdocs/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is working with CentOS 7.1, here's the approach that worked for me:

1. Configure EPEL so you can 'yum install' packages from that repo
2. Install the httpd-itk package:

   `]# yum install httpd-itk`
3. Edit /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm-itk.conf, removing the comment before the 'LoadModule' directive
4. Create your system user account (to be used in the VirtualHost block)

   `]# useradd -r itkuser`
5. Edit your VirtualHost (the example below is minimal) -- we are making request that come in for 'example.com' to run on a thread of Apache owned by the itkuser system account within the itkuser system group.

   > `<VirtualHost *:80>
   >    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dpumc.net
   >    ServerName example.com
   >    AssignUserID itkuser itkuser
   >   </VirtualHost>`
6. Restart httpd